# In list fragment clicking first time on list item do not changes the background of item

Tags: android, background, simplecursoradapter, listitem, android-listfragment

I am using list fragment to display list of item and i want that in such a way that, whenever the item is clicked its background should change and is changing too but when first time any item is clicked no change is their in the background of that item.Please help me. my code is here

Fragment class:-

```
public class Categoryfragment extends ListFragment 

 {
   DBhelper dh;
  Cursor cursor;
      @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{       
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      dh = new DBhelper(getActivity()); 
  refreshadpater();
}
  @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
     }

    public void refreshadpater()
     {
          dh = new DBhelper(getActivity());
          cursor= dh.fetchAllcategories();
      String []columns= {"category_name"};
      int []textid = {R.id.text1};
       SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list,    cursor, columns, textid);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

 }


    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
     {  

       getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
       LinearLayout ii=(LinearLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lin);
         ii.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.item_selector);

            int id1 =(int)id ;

      Subcategoryfragment fragment = (Subcategoryfragment)   getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.secondFragment);
      TextView tv = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sub);

      tv.setText("Sub-cat");
      if (fragment != null && fragment.isInLayout())
      {              
          fragment.refreshadpater1(id1);
```

//            ii.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.item_selector);

```
      } 
     }
```

}

list.xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/lin"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:background="@drawable/item_selector">

     <TextView android:id="@+id/text1"

       android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
       android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"

       />
```

```
  item_selector.xml


    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">



    <item android:state_activated="true" >
    <shape >
        <solid android:color="#FF666666" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:state_pressed="true">
      <shape>
        <solid android:color="#FF666666" />
    </shape>
    </item>


</selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

The first touch is giving focus, the second registers as a click.  You need to disable the focus so the first touch registers as a click.  This should do the trick for you:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```